# Acs712 current measure

Tags: current-measurement

I want to measure a current with Acs712 and my arduino. 
I do some math before stating measuring. 
I want to measure mA, 20 to 300. The arduino's analog precision is 1024 on 5V.
The sensor can measure 185mV/A, and it gave us 2.5 V when read 0A.

If i want to measure 20mA the sensor give me: 185mV: 1000mA= x mV : 20mA
X = 3.7 mV < 4.8 mV of analog resolution for arduino.... I can't measure it.

But if I want to measure 50mA -> X = 9.95 mV < 4.8 mV of analog Arduino's resolution.

Remember you must add 2.5v of offset! 2.5v + 9.95mV = 2.50995 V 
Now you read at the analog: 1204 : 5V = x : 2.50995 V - > 514.03

I think if I measure this small amount of current, the sensor output still to noisy... 
Is it a good idea if I add an Exponential moving average for stable the output?

Comment: Amplifying the signal?

Comment: Why not use a sense resistor

Comment: @JonRB Oh thanks. I never knew something like that existed!

Comment: @ MaNyYaCk it's a good solution, i found this solution and it's work https://goo.gl/xDyDPe .  
@JonRB your solution is very common, but i want to use the features of this IC .  

I post my code and all tests as soon as i can, for anyone interested.

Comment: @MarkCalaway I use both (and use this particular chip as well as the 200A version)  but the reason I mentioned sense resistor over HES is the current level of interest 20mA ... this is annoyingly low for HES and the errors of the HES will dominate. My usual rule of thumb is ... if < 50A use a shunt resistor otherwise use HES.  If there are complex isolation to consider then use HES.  The ACS712 is annoyingly susceptible to nearby fields